# Salir de la aplicación apretando el botón de retroceso del celular

Tags: flutter

soy algo novato estoy buscando la forma que al apretar el botón de retroceso del celular la aplicación se cierre, como debería implementar un función que detecte eso

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para ver si es pertinente preguntar sobre el tema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este seria el `Widget` que implementa esa funcionalidad. Recuerda usar `Navigator.of(context).push` en lugar de `Navigator.pus(context, ...)`.

```
import 'dart:io';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () => exit(0) ,
    child: TuWidget(),
  );
}
```

Según la [documentación](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html) de flutter es preferible usar `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');` en lugar de `exit`.

Comment: Tener en cuenta que esto no funcionará en iOS, debido a que las apps solo deben ser cerradas por el usuario y no de forma automatica.